# What's the common procedure for chaining multiple different animation in a sequence?

Tags: animation

i have a really basic question.

So, i started to learn blender about a week ago and i'm ready to make my first short movie.
So i modeled this weird animal, gave it a walk animation and... how do i transition to the next "Scene", where the animal finally finds its prey and starts feeding it through an intestinal tube to make it grow larger and more nutritious?
I really have no clue, and i'm afraid to make a mistake.
So, what's the common procedure for transitioning between different scenes? Do i simply stop the walk animation and make the animal do its thing, making a scene with about 10k frames? Or do i copy the beast model in another file for each different animation?

Thank guys for answering :))

Comment: It's up to you. Will there be camera cuts? If so, you don't necessarily have to do it all in one single animation sequence, you can break it up into 'takes' or 'scenes' and put it all together in editing afterwards. But if it's supposed to be just one single long take, then it's better to make a single long animation sequence. You can do some research on animation layers. With them you can put together different animations in the same animation sequence, it can be very useful.

Comment: uuuu didn't know about animation layers at all! Thanks!